# ¿porque mi metodo random me devuelve undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con un arreglo de frases y en la clase `App` tengo en `componentDidMount` el `setState` y todo eso pero mi funcion `selectQuoteIndex` me devuelve undefined.
En quotesData.js tengo un arreglo de objetos con dos propiedades una es quote y la otra author, luego en ese mismo archivo tengo un metodo `getQuotes` que me devuelve el arreglo de quotes.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { random } from 'lodash';
import { getQuotes } from './services/quotesData';
import Button from './components/button';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quotes: [],
      selectedQuoteIndex: null
    }

    this.selectQuoteIndex = this.selectQuoteIndex.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ quotes: getQuotes(), selectedQuoteIndex: this.selectQuoteIndex() })
  }

  selectQuoteIndex() {
    if(!this.state.quotes.length) {
      return;
    }
    return random(0, this.state.quotes.length - 1);
  }

  render() { 
    console.log(this.state.selecetedQuoteIndex);

    return (  
    <div className="App" id = "quote-box">
      <Button buttonDisplayName = "Next Quote" clickHandler = {this.selectQuoteIndex} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este código es la causa

```
if(!this.state.quotes.length) {
  return;
}
```

Cuando el componente se monta se inicializa con un state que tiene una propiedad `quotes` que es un arreglo vacío y por lo tanto el `length === 0`

```
this.state = {
  quotes: [], // El quotes se inicializa aquí
  selectedQuoteIndex: null
}
```

Así que si ejecutamos tu código tenemos que

```
if(!0) { // !0 = true
   return undefined;
}
```

Cuando niegas el `0` se vuelve `true` porque el `0` es un valor `falsey` y por lo tanto se ejecuta el `return;` que es equivalente a `return undefined;` ya que en javascript las funciones retornan algo siempre y como no especificas nada ese algo es `undefined`.

Creo que tu código se arregla si quitas la negación:

```
selectQuoteIndex() {
    if(this.state.quotes.length) {
        return random(0, this.state.quotes.length - 1);
    }
}
```

No poner un `return` en algunas condiciones es igual a escribir `return undefined` por eso no lo escribí.

Comment: probe tu `selectQuoteIndex` sin la negacion pero me sigue devolviendo undefined. :(

Comment: @CeciBenitez Tienes algún `quote` en el arreglo?

Comment: si tengo tres quotes en el arreglo.

Comment: pero me da undefined en la consola por este `console.log(this.state.selecetedQuoteIndex)`

Comment: @CeciBenitez `this.state.selecetedQuoteIndex` no es igual a `selectedQuoteIndex`. El primero está mal escrito ;)

Comment: hay Dios mio tienes razon ahora me doy cuenta mil gracias espera te voto positivo jaja